# Error al usar file_get_contents en PHP7

Tags: php, constructor, php7

Al actualizar de php 5.6 a php 7 me sale este error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 php/admirss.php on line 26
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.indeed.es/rss?q=administrativos): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in php/admirss.php on line 26
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in php/admirss.php:27 
>   Stack trace: 
>   #0 php/admirss.php(27): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')
>   #1 blogadmirss.php(69): include('...blogadmirss.php')
>   #2 {main} thrown in php/admirss.php on line 27

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php



   // define the namespaces that we are interested in
$ns = array
(
        "content" => "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/",
        "wfw" => "http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/",
        "dc" => "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
);
// obtain the articles in the feeds, and construct an array of articles

$articles = array();

// step 1: get the feed
$blog_url = "http://www.indeed.es/rss?q=almacen";

$rawFeed = file_get_contents($blog_url);
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($rawFeed);

// step 2: extract the channel metadata

$channel = array();
$channel["title"]       = $xml->channel->title;
$channel["link"]        = $xml->channel->link;
$channel["description"] = $xml->channel->description;
$channel["pubDate"]     = $xml->pubDate;
$channel["timestamp"]   = strtotime($xml->pubDate);
$channel["generator"]   = $xml->generator;
$channel["language"]    = $xml->language;

// step 3: extract the articles

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
{
        $article = array();
        $article["channel"] = $blog_url;
      ?>
      <?php
        $article["comments"] = $item->comments;
        $article["timestamp"] = strtotime($item->pubDate);
      ?>
        <ul class="pageitem">
<li class="textboxrss"><span class="header"> <?php echo $article["title"] = $item->title;?></span>
        <?php echo $article["description"] = (string) trim($item->description);?>
        </li>
<li class="menu">
<a href="<?php echo $article["link"] = $item->link;?>">
<img alt="Description" src="thumbs/tools.png" />
<span class="name">Ver oferta</span>
<span class="comment"><?php echo $article["pubDate"] = $item->pubDate;?></span>
<span class="arrow"></span>
</a>
             </li>
</ul>
<?php
        $article["isPermaLink"] = $item->guid["isPermaLink"];

        // get data held in namespaces
        $content = $item->children($ns["content"]);
        $dc      = $item->children($ns["dc"]);
        $wfw     = $item->children($ns["wfw"]);


        foreach ($dc->subject as $subject)
                $article["subject"][] = (string)$subject;

        $article["content"] = (string)trim($content->encoded);
        $article["commentRss"] = $wfw->commentRss;

        // add this article to the list
        $articles[$article["timestamp"]] = $article;
}

// at this point, $channel contains all the metadata about the RSS feed,
// and $articles contains an array of articles for us to repurpose



   ?>
```

¿Por qué puede suceder eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69290/discussion-on-question-by-lloni-error-al-usar-file-get-contents-en-php7).

Answer (score 2):

#### Debes de establecer a 1 en el **php.ini** el `allow_url_fopen`.

Si tu servidor te permite modificar desde **PHP** el **php.ini**:

> ini_set('allow_url_fopen',1);

Si no te permite en el **php.ini**:

> allow_url_fopen = 1